# How to get distinct category name from both photos & videos tables which have category name as in categories table

Tags: sql, mysql

**I want to get distinct category name from both photos & videos tables which have category name as in categories table...**

Here, m trying to execute a MySQL query to get distinct categories name from main category table which are coming in both or even in one table i.e. photos & videos...

MySQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.category_name FROM categories t1, photos t2, videos t3 WHERE
t1.category_name=t2.category OR t1.category_name=t3.category AND t2.block=0 AND 
t3.block=0 ORDER BY t1.category_name asc
```

Here's the structure of all tables...

**CATEGORIES:: (MAIN TABLE)**

[image]

**PHOTOS:: (CONTAINS PHOTOS OF ABOVE CATEGORIES)**

[image]

**VIDEOS:: (CONTAINS VIDEOS OF ABOVE CATEGORIES)**

[image]

please, help me...

Comment: Keep in mind, that `OR` has less precedence than `AND`

Comment: @Phil: i have added my question at the top..

Comment: You might want to word it as a question so it's clear what you're after *and* what's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand the question right this would work:

```
select distinct categories.name 
from categories 
left join photos on photos.category = categories.name
left join videos on videos.category = categories.name
where (photos.id IS NOT NULL) OR (videos.id IS NOT NULL);
```

But you should use a foreign key for your connection between category and photo/video.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 3):

I'd use an `EXISTS` clause

```
SELECT c.category_name
FROM categories c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM photos p
    WHERE p.category = c.category_name
    UNION
    SELECT 1 FROM videos v
    WHERE v.category = c.category_name
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the datatype of `photos.category` to (INT)
and the `videos.category` to (INT) it will be way faster when the table become larger

```
SELECT  t1.category_name 
FROM categories t1,
JOIN photos p ON p.category = t1.id
JOIN videos v ON v.category = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.category_name
ORDER BY t1.category_name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the datatype of photos.category to INT instead of varchar and do the same for videos.category, then try below query.

```
SELECT  Cat.category_name 
FROM categories As Cat,
JOIN photos AS P ON P.category = cat.id JOIN videos AS vid ON vid.category = Cat.id
GROUP BY Cat.category_name
ORDER BY Cat.category_name ASC
```

thanks.